# integrate symfony emmbedded form nicely (no padding)

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I am looking for a way to prevent symfony embeded forms to display with a padding compared to other form elements.

I am using symfony embedded forms capabilities to build a form.

I have :

```
$builder
    ->add('subProduct', new ProductType())
    ->add('calories')
;
```

and it works fine, with bootstrap 3 horizontal form layout, I have the product displayed as a subform and the extra calories .

The problem is in the view the ProductType elements appear within the  of the subproduct field instead of as their own, and thus there is a class="col-sm-2" on their left.

With one subform it remains ok though not useful, with multiple embeded subforms, I have as many "col-sm-2" as I have subforms. And the 3rd subform would be constrained in a tiny portion o the screen because three class="col-sm-2" useless labels are displayed before.

Does anyone see a way to change the way forms are displayed so as to remove the labels of the subforms a sistematic way ? Either by overriding twig bootstrap template or from within the FormType ?

the view tree to be more precise. I'd like to get rid of the second, third an fourth lines

```
<div id="appbundle_foodanalytics_ingredient">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label required">Sub product</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nom raccourci</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text"> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Calories</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="number">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried creating your own form theme? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#what-are-form-themes

Comment: well, yes, I did try. the problem is a subform is a field of the parent form. How to prevent symfony from embedding the subform in the usual div hierarchy so as to put is directly at the root level (which is the meaning of my question)

Answer (score 0):

I usually render the fields manually.Its not the best solution but it's easier than editing form's theme

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
  {{ form_errors(form) }}
  {{ form_row(form.subProduct.some_field_name) }}
  {{ form_row(form.calories) }}
  {{ form_row(form.submit, { 'label': 'Submit me' }) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```